# Is it possible to retrieve entire database at once with altered .php search?

Tags: php, api, url, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

Unfortunately I have very limited knowledge on php, XMLHttpRequest, and related matters.

I am webscraping a protein database for residue modifications, but my current approach is slow and inefficient. If for example I want to have all the modifications of protein YAL023C, I request the .json file through:

[yaam.ifc.unam.mx/Proteinas/search.php?busqueda2=YAL023C](http://yaam.ifc.unam.mx/Proteinas/search.php?busqueda2=YAL023C) :

```
{"data":[{"residue":"S","position":2,"pmid":"22814378,22817900","modification":" NtAcetylation,Phosphorylation","number":2},{"residue":"S","position":4,"pmid":"22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":5,"pmid":"22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":6,"pmid":"22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"T","position":7,"pmid":"22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"Y","position":9,"pmid":"22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"K","position":11,"pmid":"22865919","modification":"Acetylation","number":1},{"residue":"K","position":18,"pmid":"22865919","modification":"Acetylation","number":1},{"residue":"T","position":22,"pmid":"24961812","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":28,"pmid":"23749301","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":29,"pmid":"19779198,22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":30,"pmid":"19779198,22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":32,"pmid":"19779198,18407956,22817900,23749301","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":34,"pmid":"28747907,19779198,21177495,22817900,23749301","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":38,"pmid":"28747907,19684113,17330950,19779198,22817900,23749301,24961812","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":39,"pmid":"19684113,17330950,19779198,18407956,21177495,22817900,23749301,24961812","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"S","position":49,"pmid":"22817900","modification":"Phosphorylation","number":1},{"residue":"N","position":131,"pmid":"25348405","modification":"Glycosylation","number":1},{"residue":"N","position":155,"pmid":"25348405","modification":"Glycosylation","number":1},{"residue":"N","position":403,"pmid":"25348405","modification":"Glycosylation","number":1}]}
```

I repeat this for approach for a huge list of proteins which I have taken from the .json file requested from:

http://yaam.ifc.unam.mx/Proteinas/search.php?busqueda4 :

```
{"data":[{"systematic_name":"Q0010","common_name":"","location":"putative membrane protein"},{"systematic_name":"Q0017","common_name":"","location":""},{"systematic_name":"Q0032","common_name":"","location":"putative membrane protein"},{"systematic_name":"Q0045","common_name":"COX1","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0050","common_name":"AI1","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0055","common_name":"AI2","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0060","common_name":"AI3","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0065","common_name":"AI4","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0070","common_name":"AI5_ALPHA","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0075","common_name":"AI5_BETA","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0080","common_name":"ATP8","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0085","common_name":"ATP6","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0092","common_name":"","location":""},{"systematic_name":"Q0105","common_name":"COB","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0110","common_name":"BI2","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},{"systematic_name":"Q0115","common_name":"BI3","location":"cytoplasm,mitochondrion"},
```

I have no idea of the dynamics behind /search.php? which seem to originate from PHP: Hypertext. I think the database behind the search.php could have some columnar format, hence busqueda4 is returning the entire column bypassing any necessary indexing. However if I try to request all residue modifications at once by going to:

http://yaam.ifc.unam.mx/Proteinas/search.php?busqueda2 , no results are returned:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Is there any way to retrieve all data from search.php?busqueda2 format at once, just as works for the entire protein list busqueda4? I was not able to find much information on search.php requests through the browser interface.

Comment: there's no general method to do this. Either the API provides a way to download everything or it doesn't. Check the documentation of the API.

Comment: This isn't web scraping. Web scraping is when you extract information from an HTML website. If the request returns JSON, it's an API. Many APIs have a `list` operation that will return a list of all items that match various criteria.

Comment: Why is this not webscraping? The provided URLS can be parsed with requests library and beautifulsoup to retrieve the json formatted data into pandas or other dataformats.

Comment: BS is for parsing HTML/XML, not JSON.

Comment: Can be, but it does also parse JSONs apparently!

Comment: I guess so, but why would you need it? You can use the `.json` attribute in the `requests` module.